# LyX Advanced Find and Replace

Tags: lyx, find

Say I want to replace each instance of "(XXX)" (in math mode) with "[XXX]", where "XXX" stands for any arbitrary string of characters.

How might I do this?

I know that in LyX there is an "Advanced Find and Replace" feature.

Below is an example of what I've tried but clearly I'm doing it wrong. (Left: Before I hit "Replace All"; Right: After.)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about a solution, but in case it helps you search, I believe the technical term for what you're looking for is a "back reference".

Comment: Help -> User Guide section 6.13.3 in my version of LyX (2.3.3) says that "The usage of back references in the replaced text is not (yet) implemented." I don't know if that is still correct, but if it is I suppose LyX can't (currently) do what you're asking.